# Python: цикл For добавляет только последний элемент количеством в len() раз

Tags: python, циклы, list, for

Простите за очередной нупский вопрос. Честно перечитал всё про цикл For, но самостоятельно что-то не усекаю, видимо.
Нужно для каждого элемента поменять тип str на тип int.

```
#каждый элемент подсписков имеет тип str:
b = [['2018', '01', '12'], ['2018', '01', '15'], ['2018', '01', '16'], ['2018', '01', '17']]
d = []
f = []

#попытка для каждого элемента поменять тип str на int (успешная):
for i in range(len(b)):
    list.clear(d)
    d.append(int(b[i][0]))
    d.append(int(b[i][1]))
    d.append(int(b[i][2]))
    print(d)
    # print(d) выдаёт значения вида: [2018, 1, 12]
                                   # [2018, 1, 15]
                                   # [2018, 1, 16] 
                                   # [2018, 1, 17] (как раз такие мне нужны)
    f.append(d) # то есть после каждого прохода цикла в d мы собираем список вида 
#[2018, 1, 15], потом его отгружаем в список списков f.
print(len(f), f)
```

А вот в списке f получаются одинаковые значения:

```
[[2018, 1, 17], [2018, 1, 17], [2018, 1, 17], [2018, 1, 17], [2018, 1, 17]]
```

То есть вставляется последний элемент из списка b (но уже с типом int).

Код без моих комментариев:

```
b = [['2018', '01', '12'], ['2018', '01', '15'], ['2018', '01', '16'], ['2018', '01', '17']]
d = []
f = []
for i in range(len(b)):
    list.clear(d)
    d.append(int(b[i][0]))
    d.append(int(b[i][1]))
    d.append(int(b[i][2]))
    print(d)
    f.append(d)
    print(len(f), f)
```

Вывод:

```
[2018, 1, 12]
[2018, 1, 15]
[2018, 1, 16] 
[2018, 1, 17]
[[2018, 1, 17], [2018, 1, 17], [2018, 1, 17], [2018, 1, 17], [2018, 1, 17]]
```

Comment: Вы вставляете ссылку на один и тот же список. Используйте `f.append(d.copy())` либо `d = []` вместо `list.clear(d)`

Comment: Второй вариант более красивый и понятный.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Заменить

```
f.append(d)
```

на

```
f.append(d[:])
```

Comment: @Xomyak Можете поставить галку напротив ответа, который вам помог больше всего.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать функцию `map`.

```
b = [['2018', '01', '12'], ['2018', '01', '15'], ['2018', '01', '16'], ['2018', '01', '17']]

def alltoint(enum):
    for i in range(len(enum)) :
        enum[i] = list(map(lambda x: int(x), enum[i]))
    return enum

print(alltoint(b))
# [[2018, 1, 12], [2018, 1, 15], [2018, 1, 16], [2018, 1, 17]]
```